# How to pass data in $.post jquery to MVC Action method

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, controller, actionmethod

I am trying to pass data to my controller action Method by using JQuery .$Post method. I have tried multiple ways to pass data but wasn't able to receive any data from the ajax `$.post()` method.

Here is my script

```
$.post("/Home/ListChild/", {"259"}, function (data, status) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        remoteData.push({ firstName: data[i].firstName, lastName: data[i].lastName });
    }
    var template = kendo.template($("#javascriptTemplate").html());
    var result = template(remoteData);
    wnd.content(result);
    wnd.center().open();
});
```

Here is my controller method

```
public ActionResult ListChild(String userId)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Passed Value: "+userId);
    return view();
}
```

Comment: You need to formatting. And is `$.post("/Home/ListChild/",{ userId: `259'}, function(...`

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry about weird formatting, First time to post question in stackoverflow

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you stephen your solution worked!!!